# Can't find GUI of prey after installing

Tags: software-installation, gui

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and I installed **prey** successfully on it. Its CLI is working but I can't start the GUI. I followed [this link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/prey/+question/246288) but I got *command not found* error for

```
sudo /usr/lib/prey/platform/linux/prey-config.py
```

So how should I start **prey** GUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please follow steps as mentioned in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1hTK.png) to open Prey GUI.

After installing prey, launch application from terminal:-

1. go to /usr/lib/prey and then search ".py" without any quotation mark. You will see all .py files
2. Look for prey-config.py, right click on it and go to properties, copy location path.
3. open terminal, type:-

   ```
   sudo /PATH/to/prey-config.py
   ```

   It should look like as mentioned below-

   ```
   sudo /usr/lib/prey/versions/1.6.3/lib/conf/gui/linux/prey-config.py
   ```
4. GUI window will open, follow instructions.

Comment: Please try editing step three, as I  don't think it is displayed as you intended.

Answer (score 7):

In a terminal window, run:

```
sudo /usr/lib/prey/current/bin/prey config gui
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 4):

This was taken from the Prey Website:

```
sudo /usr/lib/prey/current/bin/prey config gui -f
```

The `-f` forces the GUI to display.

Comment: Please explain what this does.

Comment: Use `dplg -L` or more specifically  `dpkg -L prey |grep bin/prey` to look for a binary installed by prey. For me it is: /usr/lib/prey/versions/1.9.4/bin/prey.   You can run config gui like this: `sudo /usr/lib/prey/versions/1.9.4/bin/prey config gui`, you should see """Firing up config GUI!"""
...    Or use current which is a symlink. `ls -al /usr/lib/prey/current` shows 
"""lrwxrwxrwx 1 prey root 28 Jun 18 13:29 /usr/lib/prey/current -> /usr/lib/prey/versions/1.9.4"""

Answer (score 3):

Didn't load on my Linux Mint install.

I found the file under:

```
/usr/lib/prey/versions/1.5.1/lib/conf/gui/linux/
```

run `prey-config.py` as root and it should load.

Answer (score 2):

Using the prey_1.5.1_amd64.deb package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial) I found it at:

```
/usr/lib/prey/platform/linux/prey-config.py
```

Comment: What do you mean by finding a .deb file in a python script?

Comment: No, I downloaded the aforementioned .deb package, installed it, and found the python script at the aforementioned path.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Ubuntu 19.10 June 2020.

preyproject in ubuntu repository is old so you need to go to
https://preyproject.com/download/ And download .deb file.
And run/Install it.

After it is installed you should see service running:

```
$ systemctl |grep prey
prey-agent.service        loaded active     running   The Prey daemon.
```

To configure prey you need to run the GUI.
Prey is not added to path.
Use `dpkg -L` or more specifically `dpkg -L prey |grep bin/prey` to look for a binary installed by prey.

```
$ dpkg -L prey |less
$ dpkg -L prey |grep bin/prey
/usr/lib/prey/versions/1.9.4/bin/prey
/usr/lib/prey/versions/1.9.4/bin/prey-user
```

So, we can run the GUI using that, like this:

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/prey/versions/1.9.4/bin/prey config gui
Firing up config GUI!
```

There is a symlink installed with the package

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/prey/current
lrwxrwxrwx 1 prey root 28 Jun 18 13:29 /usr/lib/prey/current -> /usr/lib/prey/versions/1.9.4
```

So you can also run the GUI like this, and this works for any new version of prey installed/updated:

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/prey/current/bin/prey config gui


$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Codename:   eoan
```